# Determine whether two basis describe the same vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space with a finite dimension, given two different sets of basis (of the same finite dimension) of a two subspaces $U,W<V$ how can i determine whether they describe the same subspace? Is proving that the vectors that form the two basis are linearly dependent sufficient?

***To be more exact i am trying to prove that the following sets of basis describe the same subspace of  ***$ℝ^{3}$***
:***

**$\{(1,2,3),(2,-1,1)\}$ and $\{(1,0,1),(0,1,1)\}$**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Let $V$ be a vector space with a finite dimension, given two different sets of basis (of the same finite dimension) of a two subspaces $U,W<V$ how can i determine whether they describe the same subspace?

We know that if $V$ is finite-dimensional and $U$ is a subspace of $V$ such that $\dim U=\dim V$, then $U=V$.

Now, answering your question, if you can prove that $U\subseteq W$ and $\dim U=\dim W$, then you can conclude that $U=W$.

Suppose that $\{(1,2,3),(2,-1,1)\}$ is a basis of $U$ and $\{(1,0,1),(0,1,1)\}$ is a basis of $W$, then $\dim U=\dim W=2.$

Now, let $u\in U$ be arbitrary. Since $\{(1,2,3),(2,-1,1)\}$ is a basis of $U$, we can write
$$u=a(1,2,3)+b(2,-1,1)=(a+2b)(1,0,1)+(2a-b)(0,1,1).$$
Since $(a+2b)(1,0,1)+(2a-b)(0,1,1)\in W$, because $\{(1,0,1),(0,1,1)\}$ is a basis of $W$, it follows that $u\in W$. Therefore, $U\subseteq W$.

Since $\dim U=\dim W$ and $U\subseteq W$, then we have $U=W$.

Answer (score 3):

We can write the vectors in the first set as linear combinations of the vectors in the second. $[1,2,3] = [1,0,1] + 2[0,1,1]$ and $[2,-1,1] = 2[1,0,1] - [0,1,1]$. Therefore the subspace spanned by the first set of vectors is contained in the subspace spanned by the second.